# Can I call fbq('init') multiple times to use new pixel feature?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to use the [new Facebook Ads Pixel feature where I can pass through my own information about a viewer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/pixel-with-ads/conversion-tracking#advanced_match) when they're unmatched to the Facebook cookie.

However, I want to do this on a checkout page, which has fields for the user to enter in their name, address etc. They do this after the page has loaded, of course.

I can pull the information from the fields as the customer types, or once the person clicks on the buy button. However, is there going to be a problem running the `fbq('init'...)` function more than once? I'm assuming that if I don't include the init function straight away, it won't work with my standard event tracking (to track a page view etc), so I don't really want to delay it until they click on the button as I'll lose that other metric.

Alternatively, I could do this *after* they've provided their information on the next page that they see.

My questions ends up as; is there a problem calling `fbq('init'...)` more than once on a single page and will it work to send through that extra details about the customer if I do so?

Comment: Pretty sure that calling init more than once can lead to problems; at least you usually get warnings when you do.

Comment: @CBroe Agreed - that makes sense! I don't know if any other way to do it properly though!

Comment: Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can call init several times.
Events will be sent to every pixels passed to init.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/v2/2017/11/28/event-tracking-with-multiple-pixels-tracksingle/

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question. As they need to call init more than once for the "same" Pixel ID. The link you provided refers to calling init for multiple Pixel ID's. Once for each different Pixel ID. This is not the same.